# Angular nested routing and fetching data

Tags: javascript, json, angular, routes

**note:** I'm very new to this and trying to get my head around some aspects, so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

**Summary**

- I have a list of projects (/projects)
- When I click on a project, it navigates to a project summary with the URL changing to include the project ID (projects/5)
- On this page I have a button to view all issues associated with this project (/projects/5/issues)
- The projects is reading from one JSON file, the Issues are reading from another JSON file
- The projects appear fine, the project summary appears fine, the issues page doesn't
- When loading the issues page, it correctly navigates to (/projects/5/issues)
- However, here it displays ALL issues from the JSON file, not the ones associated with project ID #5.
- I believe this is most certainly due to the way I'm fetching the data back and not filtering it.

**Question**

1. When clicking on a project, then being presented the project summary page, then clicking the 'view issues' button, how do I only present issues that match that project id?

**My Issue Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import { IIssues } from './issues.interface';

@Injectable()
export class IssuesService {

    private _issuesURL = 'assets/issues-list.json';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getIssues(): Observable<IIssues[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._issuesURL)
            .map((response: Response) => <IIssues[]> response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    getIssue(id: number): Observable<IIssues> {
        return this.getIssues()
            .map((issues: IIssues[]) => issues.find(p => p.projectId === id));
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

**Issue Component TS**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Subscription }       from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { IIssues } from './issues.interface';
import { IssuesService } from './issues.service';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'issues-list.component.html',
})
export class IssuesListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    pageTitle: string = 'Issues List';
    issues: IIssues;
    errorMessage: string;
    private sub: Subscription;

    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute,
                private _router: Router,
                private _issuesService: IssuesService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                let projectId = +params['id'];
                this.getIssue(projectId);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    getIssue(id: number) {
        this._issuesService.getIssue(id).subscribe(
            issues => this.issues = issues,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

**My Issue JSON file**
I thought that including the projectID was essential here, just not entirely sure how to use it.

```js
[
    {
        "projectId": 1,
        "projectName": "Project X",
        "issueId": 11,
        "issueName": "Project X Issue"
      }
          {
        "projectId": 1,
        "projectName": "Project X",
        "issueId": 12,
        "issueName": "Project X-X Issue"
      }
]
```

**My Link on the project summary component page**

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/projects', projects.projectId, 'issues']"> View Issues </a>
```

**Issue Component HTML**

```js
<h2> {{ pageTitle }} </h2>

<ul *ngIf='issues'>
    <li *ngFor='let issue of issues'>
        <ul>
            <li> <strong> Issue ID: </strong> {{ issue.issueId }} </li>
            <li> <strong> Project ID: </strong> {{ issue.projectId }} </li>
            <li> <strong> Issue Name: </strong> {{ issue.issueName }} </li>
            <li> <strong> Project ID: </strong> {{ issue.projectName }} </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling all of your id parameters "id" ... I think they may have gotten confused somewhere. I'd suggest you begin by naming all of the parameters that expect a project Id to be projectId and those that expect an issueId be issueId.

Looking at your service, it looks like getIssue is expecting a projectId. But then it looks like the issue component is passing it the issueId?

Comment: Thanks Deborah! I refactored the code and I'm getting there now! I now have one issue displaying when click on 'view issues' on a project summary page. The error I seem to be having now is that I can only bring back one issue and produce an error when I'm trying to iterate through them. I have included the new code above titled 'issue-component.html'. The error I receive is this:

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Just FYI ... stackoverflow often prefers different problems be in different posts. It makes it easier for others with the same problem to find the answer.

Comment: As the error message states, the ngFor requires working with arrays. Is your issues property an array? No ... its not. This `issues: IIssues;` needs to be an array like this: `issues: IIssues[];`

Comment: Sure, noted. Thanks for the response and answer.